# Prolog sort list using permutation

Tags: sorting, prolog, permutation

Writing sort function, sort(A,B) in Prolog using the built in permutation Prolog function. The sort function holds if B is a sorted version of A.

```
% sorted holds if list is sorted
sorted([]).
sorted([A]).
sorted([A,B|T]) :- A=<B, sorted([B|T]).

% sort list holds if A is sorted list of B
sort(A,B) :- permutation(A,B), sorted(B).
```

The problem is: when there are duplicate values in L, R does not include these duplicates.

Output:

```
?- sort([1,4,2,5,4,4,2], X).
X = [1, 2, 4, 5].
```

How do I change the sort function so that it doesn't drop duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

permutation sort doesn't remove duplicates: testing your code

```
?- sort_([1,4,2,5,4,4,2], X).
X = [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5] .
```

(I renamed to sort_ to avoid the builtin name clash).

But [sort/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/2) does remove duplicates. You can use [msort/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=msort/2)

```
?- msort([1,4,2,5,4,4,2], X).
X = [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5].
```